# Знаки вопроса вместо кириллических символов в phpmyadmin MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin, netbeans, localhost

Подключил[image: введите сюда описание изображения] MySQL к Netbeans java, все работает, но как в localhost, так и в конечной таблице, вместо кириллических символов знаки вопроса. Как решить?

Comment: Нужно изменить кодировку. https://handyhost.ru/help/hosting/bazyi-dannyix/kak-izmenit-kodirovku-tabliczyi-mysql.html

Comment: для mysql кирилические символы не работают в кодировке utf8, нужна utf8mb4

Comment: [дубликаты где-то здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphpmyadmin%5D+%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0).